# Using protected inheritance

Tags: c++

In preparation for an exam I'm looking at an old exam and there's one question I just can't find an answer to. I don't have the correct solution to the answer and my teacher has been MIA for a while.
The question is not originally in english.

Suppose that a class CI inherits from the class Sup like: `class CI : protected Sup {`.
Why is this not a classifying inheritance?

Comment: I've never heard of "classifying inheritance" -- so you might want to define what you mean here. (I suspect its some terminology specific to your textbook or teacher)

Comment: just google "protected inheritance in C++" and follow the first link

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that consumers of the class ie. non "CI and friend classes" do not see any inherited properties/methods to Sup.

Comment: @BillyONeal You're right, I think it was partly why I had a problem understanding the question. But when using the word ["classifying"](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=classifying+meaning&oq=classifying+meaning&gs_l=hp.3..0i13l2j0i7i30j0i8i7i30.59593.2463334.0.2463390.43.28.5.3.4.4.133.1870.24j3.27.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.L3mM4Q1GWvg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.bGE&fp=e853846f6f5d0881&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=656) in the context of inheritance, it does kind of make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this not a classifying inheritance?

In general, inheritance provides a natural classification mechanism for kinds of objects, allowing the commonality of objects to be explicitly modeled. When class `D` inherits class `B` *publicly*, the relationship between the classes becomes

```
D is a B
```

This establishes a classification: "all `D`s are `B`s".

However, when the inheritance is private or protected, `D` does not become a `B`, thus failing to establish an additional classification over `D`. Essentially, private or protected inheritance can be thought of as a detail of implementation, not a detail of interface.

Comment: That made so much sense! You explain things just like my teacher (that's a complement). Thanks for the answer! :)